# Single word antonym of "flightless"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to describe birds that can fly? Am I struggling to think of a word because the default notion of a bird is that it can fly? So we generally only need to differentiate the ones that can't fly.

I've seen the term "winged" in a few google searches, but to my mind an ostrich is winged, but it is also flightless.

I guess I'm looking for the word you'd put into this blank:

> Penguins are flightless because they cannot fly.
>
> Ostriches are flightless because they cannot fly.
>
> Pigeons are ____ because they can fly.

Comment: The word "flighted" is commonly used; unfortunately I can't find an acceptable source to include this as an answer...

Comment: This seems a reputable example where "flying birds" is used: https://books.google.com/books?id=oppFLVtyfRgC&pg=PT4&dq=%22flying+birds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB4u-Em9LhAhVSm-AKHQi4C1gQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=%22flying%20birds%22&f=false But "Pigeons are flying" (without 'birds') is less clear / more confusing. But it's not clear why you want to use the "Pigeons are [single word]" construction.

Comment: Pigeons are birds.  Birds can fly.  Emus are *flightless birds* because they can't fly.

Comment: Flying is a good answer but I just wanted to point out that the reason it's difficult to find the perfect sounding word is because you generally don't say that a bird is enflightanated or anything like that, birds default to air-worthy and would need to be modified by "Flightless" if not.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you can just use *flying* to describe them; *flying birds* sounds perfectly normal and isn't a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(language)), nor does it only apply to birds in the air, cf. the title of the Wikipedia article ['Flying and gliding animals'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_and_gliding_animals).

It's obviously an awkward choice for your example sentence, where another option, *volant*, could be used instead:

> 2: flying or capable of flying

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volant))

Comment: If you think of insects capable of flying, you call them *flying insects*, so flying seems to is a good choice

Comment: "Flying birds" describes birds that are flying; it is not accurate of birds that are capable of flight, but not presently flying.

Comment: It depends on the context what it means exactly.

Comment: @youcantryreachingme would you have the same objection if somebody described moles as burrowing creatures, or lions as meat-eating mammals? At this moment most moles aren't actively burrowing, and most lions aren't currently engaged in the process of eating meat. Or described the vikings as a sea-faring culture? Most of them spent most of their time on land.

Comment: @ChrisH Nope. Just with birds, mainly for the reason in the original question - the default seems to be to think of birds as flying. "Creatures" does not have any default correlation with "burrowing", in my opinion. Neither is "mammal" associated with "meat-eating" by default - there are plant eating mammals too. Likewise, when I hear "insects", I don't think of flying or non-flying insects by default. In all 3 of those examples there is no de facto kind. With birds, however, I agree the de facto assumption is that they are flighted. Hence they become "flying [flighted] birds" ...

Comment: ... and the adjective "flying" becomes a description of present activity, rather than capability. This is basically an opinion though, based on my intuition via my experience with the language.

Comment: @youcantryreachingme The phrase 'flying birds' *can* mean "birds that are presently in flight," and that might be the more common usage, but "birds that are capable of flight" is certainly a valid usage of the phrase. It might be necessary to establish context to make sure the meaning is understood correctly, as in "The bones of nonflying birds are heavier and less hollow than those of flying birds" (https://books.google.com/books?id=oppFLVtyfRgC&pg=PT4&dq=%22flying+birds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB4u-Em9LhAhVSm-AKHQi4C1gQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=%22flying%20birds%22&f=false)

Comment: Flying squirrels and flying foxes are other instances of the word being used to describe animals that can fly (or at least glide) even when they are not currently flying.  You even see that word used to describe things that _never_ actually fly, such as buttresses or trapezes...

Comment: @Aethenosity I didn't say the term bird doesn't automatically mean they can fly. I said the default seems to be to think of birds as flying. Anyhow, I'm dipping out of the conversation. I agree "flying" is correct. I think context makes a significant difference. I think in common conversation, "flying" will be understood as birds engaged in the act of flight. I think "flighted" is less ambiguous than "flying" and works in all contexts.

Comment: When used as an adjective, the primary meaning of "flying" is "currently engaged in flight", but it can be used to mean "capable of flight". When used as a subject complement, the "currently engaged in flight" meaning is even more dominant. Similarly a "burrowing animal" could be both, but if you say "the animal *is burrowing*", the "is currently engaged" meaning dominates. With "meat-eating",  the distinction is more clear. If you say "the lion is meat-eating", that means it is a carnivore. If you say "the lion is eating meat", that means it is currently engaged in the activity.

Comment: `volant` is rather antiquated - it's a french loan word and its use in English peaked sometime before the mid 19th century.  Other than a speaker knowing the word from French, it's unlikely that even advanced English speakers would know this word.  Being misunderstood for "steering wheel" is more likely.

Comment: PS. "Flying birds" does not meet the question, which asked for a single-word antonym. "Flying", by itself, as I noted, produces "Pigeons are flying because they can fly". Well, maybe that's their rationale for flying, but it isn't clear that statement is talking about flight capability.

Answer (score 35):

Flighted.

This is the straightforward opposite of flightless.

Edit - reference below:

@WendyG Chambers's English Dictionary, Enlarged Edition with supplement containing 39 pages of additional words and phrases, W&R Chambers Limited, Edinburgh 1914:

"**Flight, n**. a passing through the air: a soaring: excursion : a sally : a series of steps : a flock of birds flying together : the birds produced in the same season : a volley or shower : act of fleeing : hasty removal.
**- adjs. Flight'ed** (Milton), flying ; Flight'y, fanciful : changeable : giddy.

**- adv. Flight'ily**.
**-n. Flight'iness**. [A.S. flyht - fléogan.] (p 350).

Comment: yep flightless/ flighted. But interestingly I can't find this in "proper" dictionaries.

Comment: @WendyG reference added to answer.

Comment: I'm not saying that this answer is wrong, but which part of the reference supports the claim that 'flighted' (incidentally, my spelling checker complains about it!) is the opposite of flightless?

Comment: If you read pretty much *any* article on flightless birds you will find several uses of "flighted" to describe the "other" birds.

Comment: @Glorfindel in short, both are correct but the meaning of "flying" requires context or clarification; "flighted" is unambiguously opposite to "flightless".

Comment: @Aethenosity agree to disagree. Let me pop our words back into the last line of the question: "pigeons are flying because they can fly", cf. "pigeons are flighted because they can fly".

Comment: I'm not sure how acceptable this is as evidence, but it may be worth considering and comparing to the pair _sightless_/_sighted_

Comment: I anticipated this would be flightfully simple.

Comment: @Magoo frightfully, even.

Answer (score 13):

Flighted

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flighted

> *flighted*
>
> (of birds) Capable of flight.

Comment: I can't help feeling that it ought to be "flit".

Comment: @RedSonja Ah, but "flit" means to fly in a particular way and I can't help feeling that _its_ past tense ought to be "flat".

Comment: @DavidRicherby To me "flit" means to run away silently, especially if you didn't pay your rent. "A moonlight flit". There is a past tense, "They've flitted."

Answer (score 11):

"Volant" would be another choice here, but it's likely to send the reader to a dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You could say, "Pigeons are flighted" as other users mentioned, or "Pigeons possess the ability of flight". It is not one word, but I guess it's very clear.

Comment: Penguins CAN'T fly though. Did you mean pigeons (as that was the blank example in the OP)?

Comment: Penguins can fly very well, (i.e. they use their wings to propel themselves) but they only do it under water.

Comment: @alephzero That's not swimming?

Comment: @alephzero while there is one definition that would fit that, contextually we are obviously using this definition: move **through the air** using wings. But my comment was more curious about why he singled out penguins over the blank sentence which used pigeons. I think it was a mistake, but maybe not.

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake but they do propel themselves through water which is a fluid so is it flight??

Answer (score 0):

I would call them just
 ***Birds*** without any adjective like 'flying' because of their [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bird) 
which includes 'wings', and  birds' wings are always used for flying:

***wing***

: one of the movable feathered or membranous paired appendages by means of which a ***bird***, bat, or insect is able to ***fly***.

(According to [MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wing))

Comment: "Birds wings are always used for flying"? Not true. Most, maybe all, flightless birds have wings.

Comment: "Pigeons are birds because they can fly." Not really a good fit.

Comment: @user307254 Better. They are certainly not **always** used for flying. But it is still no use as an answer to the question: "What is the opposite of flightless birds?" / "Birds with wings" / "Like penguins?" / "No. Other birds with wings." / "Emu?"

Comment: @user307254 just because it is the first and natural function of some birds (where it is NOT for others) doesn't mean that they are ONLY for flying. The first and natural function of wings for a penguin, ostrich, kiwi, cassowary, etc is NOT to fly

Answer (score 0):

Simply, **"Flying"** is a very strong word that says what you want.  It's not obvious, because your quest for a **plug-in unit replacement** for flightless it has thrown you off-course. "Flying" is so strong it requires adapting the sentence.

> Pigeons are flying [birds]

fullstop.  You might fill in the implied noun. The "plug-in" idea doesn't work: you wouldn't say

> Pigeons are flying because they can fly

since there's an obvious redundancy, which you would eliminate or restyle.

Answer (score -1):

In German we have it easy: 'flugfähig' and 'flugunfähig'. Deepl gave me [this translation](https://www.deepl.com/translator#de/en/Ein%20flugunf%C3%A4higer%20Vogel%0AEin%20flugf%C3%A4higer%20Vogel)

So it might be **airworthy** you are searching for, though it may only be used for contraptions and not for animals

Comment: "may only be used for contraptions and not for animals." Yeah, *airworthy birds* would at best be seen as a humorous expression.

Comment: Flight-capable.

Comment: Flightworthy... (I see it without any dash in my circles)

Comment: Airworthy mean not merely that it can fly, but that it *should*. For instance the Boeing 737 Max can fly, but it's not airworthy.

Answer (score -1):

The dodo was a kind of pigeon but lacking the need to escape predators was flightless. Pigeons in countries where predation is a danger are *flying* birds. So my suggestion is "flying". That is the best I can do. We can talk about the ***walking*** wounded or about ***talking*** stones and have those adjectives understood. To talk about a flying bird sounds strange but words become acceptable through use.

Comment: "flying" has already been suggested and is a highly up-voted answer. This answer adds nothing new.